# Navigating a json file to create desired array for jquery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, rest, autocomplete

I am programming an autocomplete function for a search bar that features names of places in Norway.

I collect the data from a REST api URL provided by a third party.
Example with input "st" and two results:

```
{
   "sokStatus":{
      "ok":"true",
      "melding":""
   },
   "totaltAntallTreff":"81280",
   "stedsnavn":[
      {
         "ssrId":"23149",
         "navnetype":"By",
         "kommunenavn":"Larvik",
         "fylkesnavn":"Vestfold",
         "stedsnavn":"Stavern",
         "aust":"214841.84",
         "nord":"6550500.29",
         "skrivemaatestatus":"Godkjent",
         "spraak":"NO",
         "skrivemaatenavn":"Stavern",
         "epsgKode":"25833"
      },
      {
         "ssrId":"506202",
         "navnetype":"By",
         "kommunenavn":"Stord",
         "fylkesnavn":"Hordaland",
         "stedsnavn":"Stord",
         "aust":"-32194.93",
         "nord":"6665261.05",
         "skrivemaatestatus":"Godkjent",
         "spraak":"NO",
         "skrivemaatenavn":"Stord",
         "epsgKode":"25833"
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to have the autocomplete array contain the "stedsnavn" features from all the returned results in the json file. so for the above example it would be [Stavern, Stord].

I built my code based off a template/tutorial i found online. When I run it now the autocomplete suggestion is the "totaltAntallTreff" feature so for the json above it would suggest 81280.

Edit: What I really need to know is how to properly query the json where I now only have response(data). I have tried several methods ($.map, $.each) but whenever I modify my code it ends up giving no autocomplete suggestions.

See my code below

```js
$(function () {
    var getData = function (request, response) {
        $.getJSON(
            "https://ws.geonorge.no/SKWS3Index/ssr/json/sok?antPerSide=5&eksakteForst=false&navn=" + request.term + "*",
            function (data) {
                (response(data));
            });
    };
 
    var selectItem = function (event, ui) {
        $("#myText").val(ui.item.value);
        return false;
    }
 
    $("#myText").autocomplete({
        source: getData,
        select: selectItem,
        minLength: 1,
        change: function() {
            $("#myText").val("").css("display", 2);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="menu-container">
    <input type="text" id="myText" />
</div>
```

Comment: I couldn't get your url to work, but given the JSON blob you posted I was able to get the wanted array from it using `response.stedsnavn.map(item => item.skrivemaatenavn);`

Comment: @GammaGames Thanks a lot,`response(data.stedsnavn.map(item => item.skrivemaatenavn));` did it for me :D

Comment: I'm glad! I'll put it into an answer so we can close this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the JSON structure provided, you could get the result with the following:

```js
let json_data = {
  "sokStatus": {
    "ok": "true",
    "melding": ""
  },
  "totaltAntallTreff": "81280",
  "stedsnavn": [{
      "ssrId": "23149",
      "navnetype": "By",
      "kommunenavn": "Larvik",
      "fylkesnavn": "Vestfold",
      "stedsnavn": "Stavern",
      "aust": "214841.84",
      "nord": "6550500.29",
      "skrivemaatestatus": "Godkjent",
      "spraak": "NO",
      "skrivemaatenavn": "Stavern",
      "epsgKode": "25833"
    },
    {
      "ssrId": "506202",
      "navnetype": "By",
      "kommunenavn": "Stord",
      "fylkesnavn": "Hordaland",
      "stedsnavn": "Stord",
      "aust": "-32194.93",
      "nord": "6665261.05",
      "skrivemaatestatus": "Godkjent",
      "spraak": "NO",
      "skrivemaatenavn": "Stord",
      "epsgKode": "25833"
    }
  ]
}

let values = json_data.stedsnavn.map(item => item.skrivemaatenavn);
values.forEach(value => {
  $("#list").append(`<li>${value}</li>`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="list"><ul>
```

As to what `json_data.stedsnavn.map(item => item.skrivemaatenavn);` is doing:

```
json_data.stedsnavn.map(item => item.skrivemaatenavn);
         // Get the "stedsnavn" key from the data, an array
                   // Map each object in the array to
                                // its "skrivemaatenavn" key
```